# Unknown Interaction Error for simple discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need some help with discord.js. I've been trying to register and respond to a slash command but always get this error. The reply can be seen on discord, but the error still occurs after and crashes the bot.

I also tried looking at the ping of the bot and it was not replying later than 3 seconds, but still get this error.

```
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (D:\discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (D:\discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (D:\discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (D:\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (D:\discord bot\index.js:41:4)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'Pong! ,178',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1099601707660496968/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTA5OTYwMTcwNzY2MDQ5Njk2ODo5RWFTYUwxNFlIOHV5c0U0YlRraFpOYnJwRzZVMFR6Y0g3VXZvU0VIYnFGU1k4RjdKcHVQZnVld29EMDQ3NnRiRXc3V0E3MHlBZlZRSlBMV3VjMGY0UjZMM0hnOEdZZXZKT2lWNm9zTkhtcGFGb3pVb2NZcGt2OUdWTndTRG1pZg/callback'
}
```

Here is my code:

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');

const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ] });

const { token, usrid } = require('./config.json');

const rest = new REST({ version:'10' }).setToken(token)

async function main(){
    const commands = [
        {
            name:"ping",
            description:"Replies with Pong!",
        },
    ];
    try{
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
        await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(usrid), {
          body: commands,
        });
        client.login(token);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
main();

//await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(usrid, rdaid)

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction =>{

        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
            await interaction.reply(`Pong! ,${client.ws.ping}`);
        };
        
});

client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

/*
client.on('messageCreate', (message) =>{ 
    if(message.author.bot){
        return;
    }
    console.log(message.content)
})
*/


client.login(token);
```

[The reply was actually sent but after that I get the error and the bot crashes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAEuh.png)

I tried deferring the reply, also no luck.